# NextJS 13 Zustand not persisting state on refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, zustand

I've followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72649255/nextjs-zustand-persist-state) to create zustand state to overcome the issue where state is set to initial state when i refresh the page in my next js 13 app.

What i have done so far :

**Wishlist.tsx**

```
import { StateCreator, create } from "zustand"
import { persist, createJSONStorage } from "zustand/middleware"

export interface WishlistSlice {
  productsIDS: any[]
  wishlistProducts: any[]
  addIdToWishlist: (productId: any) => void
  addToWishlist: (products: any) => void
  clearWishlist: () => void
  removeItemFromWishList: (id: string) => void
}

const createWishlistSlice: StateCreator<WishlistSlice> = (set) => ({
  productsIDS: [],
  wishlistProducts: [],
  addIdToWishlist: (productId) => {
    set((state) => {
      if (!state.productsIDS.includes(productId)) {
        return { ...state, productsIDS: [...state.productsIDS, productId] }
      }

      return state
    })
  },
  addToWishlist: (products) =>
    set((state) => ({ ...state, wishlistProducts: products })),
  clearWishlist: () => set({ productsIDS: [], wishlistProducts: [] }),
  removeItemFromWishList: (id) => {
    set((state) => {
      const index = state.wishlistProducts.findIndex(
        (product) => product.id === id
      )

      if (index !== -1) {
        const updatedWishlistProducts = [...state.wishlistProducts]
        updatedWishlistProducts.splice(index, 1)
        const updatedProductsIDS = state.productsIDS.filter(
          (productId) => productId !== id
        )

        return {
          ...state,
          wishlistProducts: updatedWishlistProducts,
          productsIDS: updatedProductsIDS,
        }
      }

      return state
    })
  },
})

export const useWishlistStore = create(
  persist(createWishlistSlice, {
    name: "wishlist",
    storage: createJSONStorage(() => localStorage),
    partialize: (state) => ({ items: state.productsIDS }),
    skipHydration: true,
  })
)
```

My WishlistTable client component:

**WishlistTable.tsx**

```
import { useWishlistStore } from "@/store/wishlist"

const WishlistTable = () => {
  const productsIDS = useWishlistStore((state) => state.productsIDS)
  const clearWishlist = useWishlistStore((state) => state.clearWishlist)
  const removeItemFromWishList = useWishlistStore(
    (state) => state.removeItemFromWishList
  )
  const addToWishlist = useWishlistStore((state) => state.addToWishlist)
  const wishlistProducts = useWishlistStore((state) => state.wishlistProducts)

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post("/api/wishlist", {
        productIds: productsIDS,
      })
      return data
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching wishlist data:", error)
      return null
    }
  }

  const { isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["wishlist"],
    queryFn: fetchData,
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      const products = data.products
      addToWishlist(products)
    },
    enabled: true,
  })

  const handleWishlistClear = () => {
    clearWishlist()
  }

  const handleRemoveItemFromWishlist = (id: string) => {
    removeItemFromWishList(id)
  }

  return (
  //jsx code goes here
 )
```

My Hydration file:

**Hydration.tsx**

```
"use client"

import { useEffect } from "react"

import { useWishlistStore } from "@/store/wishlist"

export default function Hydrations() {
  useEffect(() => {
    useWishlistStore.persist.rehydrate()
  }, [])

  return null
}
```

in my root layout

```
import TanstackProvider from "@/providers/TanstackProvider"
import Hydrations from "@/providers/Hydration"
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
  return (
    <html
      lang="en"
    >
      <body>
        <TanstackProvider>
              <Hydrations /> 
              {children}
        </TanstackProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

What is the issue ?

When i add item in the wishlist state `productsIDS` is persisted in the local storage. When i navigate to other page local storage stays same. But when i refresh the page (any page), productsIDS in local storage is set to initial state which is `[]`.

I would be very grateful if someone could point what am i missing here or mistake i've made while setting up the state and using it.